# LaTex Beamer: increase space between frametitle and content

Tags: latex, beamer

I'm using \usetheme{Warsaw} and want to set smaller space between frametitle and content (text, pics, formulas).
As I know, I could change it by some kind of this command:
%\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{something}{\vspace*{Xcm}}
But honestly, I don't understand it.
Maybe I could change \vspace{Y} line in beamerthemeWarsaw.sty, but I coldn't find this file. I only found reference to it in a /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST file.
Thanks in advance.
P.S. I could use \vspace{-Zcm} in every frame, but I think it is not a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my distribution the `beamerthemeWarsaw.sty` file is located at `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/themes/theme/`. But I think you should be looking at the style files in the directory `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/`. The file you want is perhaps `beamerbaseframecomponents.sty`. This has the dimensions of margins, etc.

However, I am sure you have noticed that as you fill up a slide with content, the space between the frametitle and content keeps decreasing. So, if you need to reduce this space in only some of the slides, `\vspace` might be an easier option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, definitely what I was looking for

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please accept the answer if you are okay with it.